# Failed to scrape names from next pages using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the name of [different dapps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUeRA.jpg) from a [website](https://dappradar.com/rankings/category/high-risk) across all the next pages using the `requests` module. The script that I've created can parse the names from its landing page. However, I can't find any way to grab names from the next pages.

When I observed network activity in the dev tools, I could notice that the value of params reamins the same across all the next pages. The only change that takes place within headers is the value of referer other than the cookies. I've tried to mimic the same within the following script but no luck. I always get the same names from the first page.

This is my current attempt:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = "https://dappradar.com/rankings/category/high-risk"
url = 'https://dappradar.com/v2/api/dapps'

params = {
    'params': 'UkdGd2NGSmhaR0Z5Y0dGblpUMHhKbk5uY205MWNEMXRZWGdtWTNWeWNtVnVZM2s5VlZORUptWmxZWFIxY21Wa1BURW1jbUZ1WjJVOVpHRjVKbU5oZEdWbmIzSjVQV2hwWjJndGNtbHpheVp6YjNKMFBYVnpaWEltYjNKa1pYSTlaR1Z6WXlac2FXMXBkRDB5Tmc9PQ=='
}

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'
}

page = 1

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'

    while page<=3:
        s.headers['referer'] = 'https://dappradar.com/rankings/category/high-risk/{}'.format(page)
        res = s.get(url,params=params)
        for item in res.json()['dapps']:
            print(item['name'])

        page+=1
```

How can I scrape names from the next pages using `requests`?

Comment: The site is protected by cloudflare.

Comment: The piece of code I've pasted above can flawlessly scrape data from the first page. Does `cloudflare protection` come into play when the script is supposed to go fo the next page?

Comment: If the site has an API, you should probably read its documentation instead of guess how it works. The site's developer section requires you to register so I have not pursued that further.

Comment: Accessing this site through `Python Requests` is impossible, because it uses  CloudFlare.   If the site has an API, which it seem like it does you should use that to query the site.  I was looking for the API documentation, but haven't found any yet.

Comment: you can use Selenium,(https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) for this purpose, you  get the site(https://dappradar.com/rankings/category/high-risk/2) with it and find your wanted items

Answer (score 1):

@MITHU, I also got the same type of result using requests along with 206 response status and 206 status means from server side it's success but the api is in cloudflare protection then I use [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/).
Unfortunately, it didn't work and got 403 status even though I add headers along with User-Agent. As the website is dynamic and cloudflare protection, my last attempt was using selenium. When I apply selenium, then it works smoothly.

**Script:**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
 
data = []
for page in range(1,5):
    url ="https://dappradar.com/rankings/category/high-risk/{page}".format(page=page)
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(8)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    driver.close()
    
    for name in soup.select('div.sc-fUQcsx.bVNRrx > span')[1:26]:
        name = name.text
        if name:
            name= name.replace('New', '')
            #print(name)
            data.append(name)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Name"]).to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
#print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Name

DRIP
Stable One
Kill Rich
KILLKING
MATICSTORE
FANTOM YIELDS
Forsage BUSD
Piggy Bank Machine
Baked Beans
Fisherman Joe
The Piggy Garden
BNB Miner
Fantom OneProfit
BNB Stake
BUSDMachine V2
MATICFomo
My Diamond Team
OXCASH
FireBusd
BNB100X
Tron Holders
TRON360
Piggy Bank Machine TPG Edition
Birdstake
Matic Heaven
MULTI STAKE
Tron Saving
Infinity Stones
Multimatic
DUCK NETWORK
BUSD Machine
BNB Miner V2
TURBO BUSD Miner
AngeL Nodes
BNBRACE
BNB PHOENIX
BSC Defi BUSD Miner
MaticX
TT Workers
BFRAM
Martian World
DAILY MATIC
FANTOM MINER
BNB FUTURE
8BNB.io
MATIC MINER
Fortpolis Bank
CMG MINER
BNB Maker
Snow Factory
Forsage
MetaRevo
JOJO
BUSD MINTER
CAKE MINER
BNBSafe
COMMUNITY MINER 2.0
GOLDBNB Mining Game
Crypto Egg
Cake Printer
TOMB MINER
Christmas BNB Miner
Harmony ONE Miner
AVAX MINER
Agro-Matic Staking Dapp 360% APY
Polygon Matic Miner
Baby Chick
BSC BNB Miner
Metarium
Pinaki
AVAX Miner
SPELL MINER
Rapid BNB
TitaniumChain
USDC MINTER
Harmony Factory
Rewardeum
DotMiner Finance
LINK MINER FINANCE
Ada Miner
USDT Miner
FTM Fantom Miner
SHIBA MINER FINANCE
BNB Stable
TTSTAR MINER
BUSD MOONMINER
CAKE MINER FINANCE
ICE MINER
TTPIRATES
ADA.finance
BNB Hotels
Phantom Chain
Levenue
Matic Race
Bnb Farming
PolyMiner
BtcMiner
BUSD Miner
BUSD SmartPool
BNBINSIDER
```

Answer (score 0):

the request you are making to `https://dappradar.com/v2/api/dapps` adds a randomized string as `params` to the url, so using that is probably not going to be helpful

what you are using is not a public api [read further](https://www.reddit.com/r/dappradar/comments/kxdgo9/dappradar_api/).

you could use something like `selenium or puppeteer` to emulate a user clicking trough the site (note: this may be against the terms of service).

Comment: Although the value of params look randomized at first glance, in reality it is not. I found the same params exactly like how it was 10 days back.

Comment: i don't know if they change when the data is updated, but if not, i guess you could just open the network tab and watch out for any json data that is incoming (copying the value parameter each time you open the next page)

Comment: You surely didn't read my post above. The value of params stays the same in dev tools accross all the next pages.